# Google Cloud speech simple problems with no response

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have error requests. I still don't know where to invoke request and how to fetch response. Where do I set API key?

```
var initialize = new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer();
    initialize.ApiKey = "key";
    var speech = new Google.Apis.Speech.v1.SpeechService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer {
    });

    var recognizeReq = new Google.Apis.Speech.v1.Data.RecognizeRequest();
    var recognitionConf = new Google.Apis.Speech.v1.Data.RecognitionConfig();
    recognitionConf.LanguageCode = "pl-PL";
    recognitionConf.SampleRateHertz = 16000;
    recognitionConf.Encoding = "FLAC";
        recogniseReq.Config = recognitionConf;

    var aud = new Google.Apis.Speech.v1.Data.RecognitionAudio();
    string path1 = @"c:\output.flac";
    //var bytesAudio = File.ReadAllBytes(path1);
    aud.Uri = path1;
        recognizeReq.Audio = aud;

    var variable = speech.Speech.Recognize(recogniseReq);

    variable.Key = "key";
    //variable.OauthToken = 

    variable.Execute();

    Google.Apis.Speech.v1.Data.RecognizeResponse resp = new Google.Apis.Speech.v1.Data.RecognizeResponse();
    var lista = resp.Results;
```

Answer (score 0):

I change software and now I use  Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 library
I managed to save voice using NAudio
and I tried to send continuos request to cloud, but it doesn't work

'''
waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

```
            waveFile.Flush();

            audio5 = RecognitionAudio.FromBytes(e.Buffer);

            var result = client.LongRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio5);
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

This solves problem.
problem with buffer is for a longer time.
I get into trap like others.
found solution in dispute about bug (from Google of corse ;) )
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/95b32e683ba534883b8a7f3c979deee101ba3678/speech/api/Recognize/InfiniteStreaming.cs